# SSRS Report Interface Takes a Long Time to Load, Only in One Environment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

We have a collection of reports that are deployed to several environments. The reports work as expected in all environments except for one. In this particular environment, the reports - which normally take a couple seconds to load - take 2-3 minutes to load the interface. It seems like the more dataset-driven drop down parameters the report has, the longer it takes to load. When I look at ReportServer..ExecutionLog3, I can see that the Dataset Executions are taking 6+ seconds to load each, whereas these take a few ms in every other environment. However, when I have SQL Profiler running, I can see that the batch containing the dataset executed in less than 100ms. So there's over 5 seconds of just waiting around. I figure this has to be something environment specific. I've brought in our network admin to run wireshark, as we were thinking it might have something to do with AD authentication over a slow link, but he didn't see anything unusual.

Any ideas? Our client is really starting to get unhappy about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same report/parameter set in each environment, or different in each environment?

Comment: If the batches are finishing in 100ms then it doesn't sound like a SQL Server problem. Report server has dodgy network connectivity? If it's a virtual guest (especially on ESX/ESXi) do you have the appropriate vNIC drivers installed for the guest OS?

Comment: The network admin didn't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Same report/parameter set in each environment.